# How to trim a form field starting with blank spaces in javascript for validation?

Tags: javascript

I want to trim a field in form so that if the field starts with 1 or more blank spaces i can trim it and do neccesary validations on the actual string.

Comment: Tada! https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var orig = "   foo  ";

console.log( orig.trim() ); // "foo"
```